# Script / Code to check an output of a webpage and return result

Tags: c#, php, .net, perl

I am looking for a script e.g. perl or code - C# etc. in order to check a webpage for a string.

For example to check if a php page is running, we can echo Hello World, and the script would then check for the string "Hello World" on the webpage output and return true or false.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch the data with [LWP](https://metacpan.org/search?q=lwp), then run a pattern match over the retrieved document.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a [ScreenScraper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenscraping#Screen_scraping) in your preferred language. You can use it to get the HTML output of the site and get a specific part, like paragraphs, images or - like in your case - a single string (mostly using XPath).